# How to use back button on toolbar with sliding navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, back-button

I have a `Activity` in which I have created `NavigationDrawer` functionality and rest I have fragments using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

My problem is I want that if I navigate using navigation drawer to all fragments except home like photos, notification, etc. It must show a back button instead of hamburger icon and also includes sliding navigation. I am not able to implement this.

Also want to change toolbar back button color. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

to change back button color try this.

```
<style name="toolbar_theme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/arrow_color</item>
</style>
```

**or**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/arrow_color</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: this may be some parent theme issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do `actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_new_icon);` where toggle is your ActionBarDrawerToggle instance

Answer (score 0):

To change Drawer icon to Back arrow use:

```
MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
//disable the toggle menu and show up carat
theDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); // add this
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_layout,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Add this code in your Drawer Item's Fragment Transaction without the Home Fragment

To revert back the change:

overwrite `onBackPressed()` in your Activity

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // turn on the Navigation Drawer image; 
    setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true)
}
```